# How can I make the WPF TextBox scroll text into caret position?

Tags: wpf, textbox, scroll, caret

The standard WPF TextBox control does not scroll the overflowing text into caret position as one types text into the control. Is it possible to create this behavior in a singeline WPF TextBox control? If so - How?
An example of this behavior is the default way a HTML input type=text acts in most (if not all?) browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TextBox will have that behavior unless it is allowed to stretch infinitely.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                Margin="5">
        <TextBlock Text="No Horizontal Scrolling:" />
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 MinWidth="100" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                Margin="5">
        <TextBlock Text="Horizontal Scrolling:" />
        <TextBox Width="100" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                Margin="5">
        <TextBlock Text="Horizontal Scrolling:" />
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 MinWidth="50"
                 MaxWidth="100" />
    </StackPanel>
    <DockPanel Margin="5">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                   Text="Horizontal Scrolling:" />
        <TextBox />
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```